# node js script exits prematurely

Tags: mysql, node.js, mongodb, promise, sequelize.js

Promise newbie here.

I'm trying to retrieve `icon_name` field from `asset` database, `Equipment` table in mongodb
and update `icon_id` field in `equipments` database, `equipments` table in mysql.

I have about 12,000 records with `icon_name` field in `Equipment`.

The script runs successfully however it doesn't seem to go through all the records.
When I check the `equipments` table there are only about 3,000 records updated.

I tried running the script several times and it appears to update a few more records each time.

My suspicion is the database connection is close before all the queries are finished but since I use `Promise.all` I don't know why it happened.

Here is the script

```js
const _ = require('lodash'),
    debug = require('debug')('update'),
    Promise = require('bluebird')

const asset = require('../models/asset'),
    equipments = require('../models/equipments')

const Equipment = asset.getEquipment(),
    my_equipments = equipments.get_equipments(),
    icons = equipments.get_icons()

Promise.resolve()
.then(() => {

    debug('Retrieve asset equipments, icons')
    return Promise.all([
        icons.findAll(),
        Equipment.find({ icon_name: { $ne: null } })
    ])
})
.then(([my_icons, asset_equipments]) => {
    debug('Update equipments')
    const updates = []

    console.log(asset_equipments.length)
    asset_equipments.forEach((aeq, i) => {

        const icon_id = my_icons.find(icon => icon.name === aeq.icon_name).id
            up = my_equipments.update(
                { icon_id },
                { where: { code: aeq.eq_id } }
            )

        updates.push(up)
    })


    return Promise.all(updates)
})
.then(() => {
    debug('Success: all done')
    asset.close()
    equipments.close()
})
.catch(err => {
    debug('Error:', err)
    asset.close()
    equipments.close()
})
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code looks fine but spawning 12000 promises in parallel might cause some trouble on the database connection level. I would suggest to batch the concurrent requests and limit them to let's say 100. You could use `batch-promises` (https://www.npmjs.com/package/batch-promises)

Basically something like

```
return batchPromises(100, asset_equipments, aeq => {
            const icon_id = my_icons.find(icon => icon.name === aeq.icon_name).id;
      return my_equipments.update({ icon_id }, { where: { code: aeq.eq_id } });
        });
```

Comment: Works very well, thank you. The only downside is it's very slow. Took maybe 10 minutes.

Comment: It turns out it is slow because I did not create an index at code field. Probably nothing to do with the batch-promises library.